# View functions in an object [Eclipse C++]

Tags: c++, eclipse

So i am having trouble viewing the member functions of my declared objects. I am using a MAC and i have an object. I want to see what kind of functions exists in that object. I cannot find the shortcut key for this so i was wondering if someone else knew it?

On my windows computer for java it use to be ctrl + space but that does not seem to work for c++ in either my mac or windows. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the *Windows Language Services Utility*. The default method to switch between languages on Windows is to use the `ctrl + space` keyboard shortcut, which could be conflicting with the keyboard shortcut for auto-complete in Eclipse.

To get rid of this conflict, you will need to remove all other languages from your computer. Here is a solution:

> *You can find out what languages you have set up by going to **Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages (tab) and then Change Keyboards** (again, how obvious…). You’ll see a list of languages installed – remove any that you don’t want (click the language and then click the Remove button) until you only have the ones you want left. That fixed it for me, but you can also check the Advanced Key Settings tab to make sure that none of the keyboard shortcuts that are set include Ctrl-Space.* - [Robin's Blog](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-solve-the-ctrl-space-auto-complete-not-working-problem-in-eclipse/)

Alternatively, you may also want to check whether there is any other conflict with the default keyboard shortcut with Windows and Eclipse C++ IDE:

> *... but you can also check the **Advanced Key Settings tab** to make sure that none of the keyboard shortcuts that are set include Ctrl-Space.* - [Robin's Blog](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-solve-the-ctrl-space-auto-complete-not-working-problem-in-eclipse/)

Comment: Thats what i get when i do ctrl+space. It does not show me the functions inside of ofstream

Comment: _@AkshayMandania I _think_ for eclipse c++, the functions do not show for an imported library. it only works if the function is in the program itself.

Comment: I used visual studios by duel booting and i still do not get the option to view the functions of an imported library.....Its so weird..

Comment: @AkshayMandania I thought you were using Eclipse?